# Relationship between physical registers and Intel SIMD variables?

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics

What is the relationship between physical processor registers and the variables used in Intel intrinsics (e.g. __m128)?

A diagram explaining SIMD typically shows 2 registers but references on the Intel [forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/286732) to "register pressure" and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190467/sse2-instructions-not-working-in-inline-assembly-with-c/4190616#4190616) to "register coloring" suggest there is more going on.

Can any number of variables representing registers be declared? How can this be when they're closely tied to a finite physical resource? What should one be aware of regarding how physical registers are chosen? What happens if more registers are declared than exist?

Can multiple pairs of registers be active at the same time?

Are there different types of physical registers?

Comment: Just like with the general purpose registers, the compiler is responsible for scheduling which physical register holds which variable at any particular time. Using too many variables means it will have to move things in and out of physical registers more, so it makes sense to write your code in such a way as to limit the number of actively in use variables at any point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable types like _m128, _m128i, _m128d, ... are there mainly to protect you.  They ensure that you are not attempting to use standard operators like +, -, &, |, ==, ... and ensure that the compiler will throw an error if you are attempting to assign the wrong types.  These types force the compiler to load themselves into the appropriate register (XMM* in this case), but still give the compiler the freedom to choose which one, or store them locally on the stack if all appropriate registers are taken.  They also ensure that any time they are stored on the stack, they maintain the correct alignment (16 byte alignment in this case), so that intrinsic instructions that rely on alignment don't cause GPFs.

You may tightly tie one of these variables to a physical register if you like using the asm constructs:

`__m128i myXMM1 asm( "%xmm1" );`

But it's better to just let the compiler do its magic and choose the registers for you to allow better optimization.

Any number of these variables can be declared, and even overbooking your XMM register store might not result in using stack space, as long as your working set of registers remains small.  Compiler scoping will usually realize when a value is no longer used and allow the optimizer to not store it back to the stack.  Sometimes you can help the compiler out by creating your own scoped stack frame:

```
__m128i storedVar;
{
  __m128i tempVar1, tempVar2, tempVar3;
  // do some operations with tempVar1 -> 3
  storedVar = tempVar1;
}
{
  __m128i tempVar4, tempVar5, tempVar6, tempVar7, tempVar8;
  // do some operations with tempVar4 -> 8
  storedVar = tempVar4;
}

return storedVar;
```

Since the variables go out of scope at the closed curly brace, the compiler sees that the registers which used to contain those values are now freed up, so it doesn't need to exceed the total number of available XMM registers.

If you do overbook your register store, and all values need to be maintained, then the compiler will allocate the appropriate size on the stack and ensure that it is properly aligned, and the value of the XMM register will be swapped out to the stack to make room for a new value.  Keep in mind that the stack space is well cached, so writes and reads there are not as harmful as you might have expected.  The real hit that you take is the necessity of the extra move operations to swap them in and out.

There are different types of physical registers by width (64-bit, 128-bit, 256-bit, 512-bit), obviously associated with the corresponding C/C++ intrinsic data type.  The different "flavors" for a given width ("__m128i", "__m128d", ...) can actually all reside in any of the registers of the given width.  The type forces you to use the appropriate intrinsic type (`_mm_and_si128` vs. `_mm_and_pd`, for example), which in turn generates an appropriate version of the instruction.

Something like the "and" is a good example because the resulting operation will be identical regardless of type - a bitwise "and".  But using the wrong type can incur latency according to what I've read in the Intel docs.  The integer instructions and floating point instructions have separate execution queues, and whenever data has to move from one execution queue to the other, there is a penalty.  So generally it is good practice to choose the appropriate data type so that the appropriate instructions can be generated, and stay within the realm of that data type.